# MalformedURLException when loading an HTML file from system

Tags: java, url, jeditorpane, malformedurlexception

So I'm working on a browser (just cause) and I keep getting a `java.net.MalformedURLException`. I'm trying to set a `JEditorPane`'s page to a file which is loaded off of my computer. Here's the code:

```
  public Browser() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    URLField = new JTextField("Enter the full address of the website:");
    displayWindow = new JEditorPane();
    try {
        homeURL = new URL(getCurrentDirectory() + "/resources/home.html");
        displayWindow.setPage(homeURL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.addTab("Home", displayWindow);

    add(URLField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(displayWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

And here's the error I get:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: x
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.whowantsakookie.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:25)
    at net.sourceforge.whowantsakookie.browser.Browser.main(Browser.java:42)
```

The lines it's referring to are line 25 and 42. 
Line 25:

```
homeURL = new URL(getCurrentDirectory() + "/resources/home.html");
```

Line 42:

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do `new URL("file://" + getCurrentDirectory().replaceAll('\\', '/') + "...")`. Or something nicer.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please make an answer out of that so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Establish a `File` object.
2. Check it exists (sanity check).
3. `URL url = file.toURI().toURL();`

Note that doing it this way will ensure that things like space chars in the file name/path are correctly encoded.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of using URIs before.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not entering the string 'http://' before the url you are providing in the JTextField. Please check.

Comment: Thanks, but I had to put `file://` since I was loading it offline.